# SVN ignore being ignored

Tags: svn, ignore

In my "application" dir, I have a "logs" directory and a "config" directory, both under version control, both having locally modified files, both told to ignore these files. However only one of the ignores works:

```
> pwd 

  website.com/trunk/application/

> svn propget -R svn:ignore

  logs - *.log
  configs - *.ini

> svn status

  M  logs/website.log
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN just won't ignore a folder, despite propset svn:ignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689029/svn-just-wont-ignore-a-folder-despite-propset-svnignore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from Daniel Gehringer's answer, which is part of the solution, `svn:ignore` only works for non-versioned files. When files are versioned, it's expected that they show status `M` when they're changed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can add descriptions to `svn:ignore`. The list should be simply

```
*.log
*.ini
```

Comment: Where do you see descriptions? The properties are what you say they should be. Propget option -R is prepending directory names to show me which directory those properties are set on.

Comment: @RADA, I didn't realize this, sorry. So Sander's answer is probably the correct one.