# Not able to commit main.storyboard file on svn

Tags: xcode, svn

I am using command line svn (also I have tried visual svn, there is also same problem I have faced).

1. firstly I have imported project directory on svn URL
2. I have taken checkout of svn repository
3. then I have opened a project and make some change in storyboard file.
4. and then commit, it committed successfully.
5. then I have taken update using svn update
6. again made some change in Main.storyboard and tried to commit
   but this I am not able to commit storyboard file. this is happening with storyboard file only
   I got the following error
   error - svn: E175002: Unexpected server error 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/scm/svn/ACI-EM/!svn/wrk/1d01e196-c6d9-43c5-87e2-7a3513047a8f/Code/trunk/IOS/SVNDemoProject/DemoProject/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard'

another file is working fine.
I didn't get where I am going wrong.

Comment: The exclamation mark `/!svn` looks fishy. Run `svn status`.

Comment: @shallowThought -\n- M       DemoProject/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard -\n-
?      DemoProject.xcworkspace/xcshareddata -\n-
M       DemoProject.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/thinkuser.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

Comment: The error does not fit, but: you want to ignore xcuserdata, as it always changes. Try if ignoring cures your issue. If you do not know how, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11691698/1457385).

Comment: @shallowThought it is not working, getting the same error.