# How to set svn:ignore with multiple values?

Tags: svn

Let's say I want to set the **svn:ignore** property for directory **dir1** with multiple values, *file1*, *file2*, and *file3*.
How can I do this via command line, without using a text editor (to set the property value)?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Type exactly like here with line breaks:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "file1
file2
file3" dir1
```

If you want to pass a list from another command, try [`xargs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs).
Unfortunately, the **svn** command doesn't allow reading from `stdin` with `-F -`.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that you meant "propset" (not "propget")

Comment: Sucks or not, it was something new and fresh vs CVS at a time. Now it may look outdated in comparison to git, hg, bzr etc but still works well in many projects.

Answer (score 24):

One line solution:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "file1"$'\n'"file2"$'\n'"file3" dir1
```

Comment: This one worked fine for me in the presence of the `^` substitution character used to specify the root of the svn repository in the property `svn:externals`. The multi-line solution wasn't working because the shell was trying to interpret the `^`

Comment: This works fine, but I'd like to know why. What does the $ character do here? It is normally used to start a variable, correct? Also note the single quotes around the `\n` are required, and must be single, while the double quotes around the filenames are only required if they have special characters like spaces.

Comment: @trysis found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script

Answer (score 21):

Adding multiple entries is much easier. Use the following command:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

This will open a text editor. Now you can add multiple entries easily.

Comment: only if you have set up an svn editor, which you can do via `export SVN_EDITOR=vi`

Comment: ...or simply $EDITOR

Answer (score 16):

Use:

```
cat > ignorelist << END
file1
file2
file3
END

svn propset svn:ignore -F ignorelist dir1
```

Or without an external file, and assuming you're on Linux or a system with `/dev/fd`:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F /dev/fd/0 dir1 << END
file1
file2
file3
END
```

Comment: Thanks, it is clear. But how to set property value without using an external file?

Comment: Regarding `/dev/fd`: What does it refer to? Floppy disks? [/proc/PID/fd/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)? Or something else?

Comment: /dev/fd/0 is a reference to standard input - it can be used in situations like here where a command wants a filename and the input data is not stored in a file

Answer (score 1):

In powershell:

```
$ignore = "*.dll`n*.xml"
svn propset svn:global-ignores $ignore .
```