# Error while setting svn externals property

Tags: svn

I have a problem setting (or changing) an `svn:externals` definition in my local `svn` working copy. First

```
svn propget svn:externals
```

lists the following:

```
https://path/to/mytool/tags/1.0.8 mytool
```

I want to change this property so it points to a tag with revision number `1.0.9`. I tried the following:

```
svn propset svn:externals https://path/to/mytool/tags/1.0.9 mytool
svn: Error parsing svn:externals property on 'mytool': 'https://path/to/mytool/tags/1.0.9'
```

and

```
svn propset mytool svn:externals https://path/to/mytool/tags/1.0.9
svn: Setting property on non-local target 'https://path/to/mytool/tags/1.0.9' needs a base revision
```

and the same of the above with the URL and the target directory set in quotes (as found as answer to the same problem), which both yields an error

```
svn: Explicit target required ('https://path/to/mytool/tags/1.0.9 mytool' interpreted as prop value)
```

So what the heck am I doing wrong? How to change the property correctly. `svn help` does not really help here...

Addendum: With `svn propedit svn:externals .` it does seem to work. I am able to change this property, which I can commit now. But `propset` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify the `PROPVAL` in the form of `TARGET-DIRECTORY EXTERNAL-PATH` and set it on parent directory of `TARGET-DIRECTORY`. So in your example that would be...

```
svn propset svn:externals "mytool https://path/to/mytool/tags/1.0.9" .
```

...to be executed in the directory parent to the directory called `mytool`.

**Update:** To do this with multiple lines, the normal approach I use is to write the properties into a file, e.g. `externals.txt`, then set it up with

```
svn propset svn:externals -F externals.txt .
```

Under Linux you might also get away with [this one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15084970/1529709), but I'm not aware of a Win32 analogue for this.

SVN does not particularly shine when it comes to this task :/

Comment: Ok thanks for this clarification. But when I need to set multiple externals, I tried something like `svn propset svn:externals "mytool https://path/to/mytool/tags/1.0.9\nothertool https://path/to/my/othertool/tags/2.4.2" .` giving a parsing error.  But according to the help this should work like this...

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but solution from @zb226 didn't work.

I was trying all kind of things and it was some sort of bug and maybe it has something to do from changing server from linux Centos to Windows(VisualSVN). The problem was in missing space after **"** symbol (in this case missing space in front of "mytool"

Without extra space it just didn't work and parsing error occurs. In example I show how it worked for me. It is basically the same solution as @zb226 proposed but with one extra space.

```
svn propset svn:externals " mytool https://path/to/mytool/tags/1.0.9" .
```