# How can I exclude the .sass-cache folder from my SVN repository?

Tags: compass-sass

I am a compass sass beginer.
[image]
I don't want to upload this folder to svn, it is not useful at all. how to set compass to move it to other place?

Comment: why no people answer my question

Comment: Old question but here is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14935393/684932

Comment: @RaphaelDDL: That thread does not answer the question. It only explains why Sass uses a cache in the first place. It doesn't tell you how to exclude it from SVN. The link in the accepted solution is better, and leads you to a solution something like `svn propset svn:ignore '.sass-cache' .`

Comment: @bergie3000 The link I provided answers the question inside the image, which is "can sass-cache folder be moved to other place?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory is already in the best place, i.e. with the rest of your Compass files, so it's probably a better idea to just tell SVN to ignore it. It's a long time since I've used SVN but here's a [good write up on the svn:ignore property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/414910/1777801).