# Why does Sass cache folder get created

Tags: sass

I have started trying out Sass for my css work. In the directory where my Css file resides I see a '.sass-cache' folder too. Can any one tell me why is this folder created and is it safe if I delete it.

thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @cimmanon I've had issues with .sass-cache inhibiting pushes to development environments when multiple developers use/change it.  If it can be removed from the project folder, this would be better.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

By default, Sass caches compiled templates and partials. This dramatically speeds up re-compilation of large collections of Sass files, and works best if the Sass templates are split up into separate files that are all @imported into one large file.

Without a framework, Sass puts the cached templates in the `.sass-cache` directory. In Rails and Merb, they go in `tmp/sass-cache`. The directory can be customized with the `:cache_location` option.

If you don’t want Sass to use caching at all, set the `:cache` option to `false`.

You can configure the Sass cache location by setting a Sass option in your compass configuration file like so:

```
sass_options = {:cache_location => "path\to\tmp\sass-cache"}
```

Source: [Sass reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)

Comment: Is there any way to recover sass file from sass cache?

Comment: You can also use `--cache-location PATH` when using the command line.

Comment: If you're using **grunt-contrib-sass**, the relevant options are `cacheLocation` and `noCache`: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass

Comment: I'm fine with improving speed, but why then does it keep all the old ones? Causing you to end up with huge masses of files.

Answer (score 9):

If your main problem is "inhibiting pushes to development environments when multiple developers use/change it", you can add it to your .gitignore file. As stated in the other answer, Sass cache files speed up compilation based on whether a Sass file has changed since last compile.

In my experience it's standard practice to consider them temporary files, and omit them from version control.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP does not indicate a reason why they wish to remove it (the version control comment was made by someone else).  There are legitimate reasons why one might need to destroy .sass-cache.

Comment: Missed that those were two different users. Leaving up as it's information that addresses one user question raised on this post.

Comment: I believe this answer answers the next obvious question one might ask. 
It's very useful, despite not on topic with the initial question.