# Rails on EC2 - wicketpdf - permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, permissions

I have set up and Elastic Beanstalk instance, where I'm running Ruby 2.1 with Passenger. My app uses WicketPDF gem to generate PDF files from HTML.

How do i make a script or an config file in .ebextensions that handles these permissions on after deploy hook.

I have no idea how to write the commands to enable my Rails app, to have the necessary permissions.

This is the error given:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - ./.sass-     cache/4cf4513a295495886c7f76b542d7ea7acf7dc73a/(__TEMPLATE__)c
```

Comment: did you try giving permission of the `cache` directory to the `deployer` user ?

Comment: i tried sudo chmod 0777 -R on the tmp directory, but it does not work. Don't think i have a deployer user, just ec2-user and root

Comment: make sure the `tmp` dir has read/write permission for `ec2-user`.. I usually check this using `ls -la`

Comment: looks like it does, but for user webapp. `drwxrwxrwx  4 webapp webapp  4096 Oct  7 13:20 tmp`

Comment: ok, it looks like there was a .sass-cache in app root directory, after removing it, it works, the questions is now how the heck :)

Comment: so i restarted the app server on ec2 instance, now i have to manually set the chmod on cache folder again so that the Rails.cache.clear command works :/

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934800/why-does-sass-cache-folder-get-created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sass created a .sass-cache folder in root dir of my Rails app, after deleting it, the wicket gem created the pdf no problem.

Thanks @illusionist