# Svn ignore issues, no other questions/answers have helped

Tags: macos, svn

I am using `svn` on command line on OSX.
In my project I want to ignore `cache` and `sessions` directories but none of the other topics have helped and I can't see why not.

```
/my-project/storage/framework/
                             cache/
                             sessions/
                             views/
```

I want to ignore `cache` and `sessions` and their contents from version control. They keep updating or adding new files. I already have some under version control and I don't know how to remove the ones already under control and ignore them all in future.

What I have:

```
> svn stat
?       storage/framework/cache/96
?       storage/framework/sessions/527212b940937ee8b637e516a5169aa933d03ce0
```

So far I've tried:

```
> cd storage/framework
> svn propset svn:ignore cache .
> svn proplist
Properties on '.':
 svn:ignore
>svn propget svn:ignore
cache

>svn status
 M      .
?       cache/96
?       sessions/527212b940937ee8b637e516a5169aa933d03ce0
```

Should the `cache` directory not be ignored now?
Then I could do the same for sessions and it's contents if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
framework>svn pg svn:ignore -v
Properties on '.':
  svn:ignore
    cache
    sessions
```

and as result

```
>svn st
A       framework
?       framework\views
```

for

```
>dir /B /S
Z:\WC\framework
Z:\WC\framework\cache
Z:\WC\framework\sessions
Z:\WC\framework\views
Z:\WC\framework\cache\96
Z:\WC\framework\sessions\527212b940937ee8b637e516a5169aa933d03ce0
```

Comment: I updated the property svn:ignore to include both and when I run `framework>svn pg svn:ignore -v` I get the same output as you but when I run `svn st` I still get the ? beside the files I want ignored

Answer (score 0):

I tried different combinations of ignore paths to the files in the folders such as `sessions/*` and found they didn't work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414879/how-to-remove-a-file-folder-from-a-svn-repository-and-add-to-the-ignore-list?rq=1) actually was the answer I partially needed. I was previously unintentionally attempting to ignore the directories when all I needed was to ignore the contents of each of them. So because the directories were already under version control I could not ignore them and their contents. I needed to ignore the contents on their own.

I ended up including a svn:ignore property in both `cache` and `sessions` directories to ignore all files with `*`

Then I removed the already existing files from the repository using `svn rm --keep-local cache/*` and `svn rm --keep-local sessions/*` before commiting all the changes and now the contents in both directories are ignored.